# sequence of polynomials converging uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I have $f(x) = xsin(1/x)$ if $x>0$ and $0$ if $x=0 $. I wanna see if there exists a sequence of polynomials converging to $f$ uniformly on $I$ when (a) I=$[0,1]$ and (b) I=$(0,1]$. I think it is true for both cases but about how to justify it, I'm not sure. For case (a),  $f(0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow} f(x)=0$, so $f$ is continuous and by Weirestrass approximation theorem, Bernstein polynomials converge uniformly to $f$. **Is this reasoning correct?**. For part (b) I'm stuck. The interval is not closed. **Any help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), it is correct. And for (b), since $(0,1]\subset[0,1]$ and since the convergence is uniform on $[0,1]$, it is also uniform on $(0,1]$.

Comment: What about $I=[1,\infty)$? It's not true in this case, but how can I prove it? I have to show for any sequence of polynomials $P_n(x)$ , $sup_{x\in[1,\infty)}|P_n (x)-f(x)| \nrightarrow 0$?

Comment: @Jack This is a distinct question. Please post it as such.